# Python dict type agonistic functionality in C++ Hashtable

Tags: python, c++

I need to run through a list of various types of modules to handle each type in a group by itself, but won't know the type/number of types/number of modules until the code is running. In python, this would be easy, I take the module types as a dict key and then save off the module targets to process together as lists. I wrote up a crappy python bit below as an example:

```
module_values = dict()

for mod_target in modules:

   if mod_target.type not in module_values.keys():
       module_values[mod.type] = list()

   module_values[mod.type].append(mod_target)
```

But I need to do this in C++, which wants me to know how many lists and what the module types are beforehand for the compiler. I was thinking about making a custom struct and tossing into a hashtable, but I'm still not sure how to tell it take in any module_target.type. Any one know how to get a type agnostic dict functionality via a C++ hashtable?

Comment: This is a pretty open ended question. It sounds like "How do you put different types in a container." You should look into abstract base class and smart pointers.

Comment: What operation(s) do you imagine on the "`mod_target`" objects? One way or the other you'll need to type-erase the representation to store it into, e.g., a `list<X>`. For example, if there is a common entry point, for simplicity taking no arguments, you could use `std::function<void()>` as such a type. If you need multiple operations you may use something similar (i.e., something using/producing a class hierarch) but with a suitable mix of operations.

Comment: You should post incomplete C++ that attempts to do what you need and thereby explains what you are looking for rather than Python. There are many ways to set up something like a container of heterogenous types in C++. That can mean a lot of things. Which you need depends on the details.

Comment: `std::map<ModuleType, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IModule>>>`?